# Web scraping with python and using loops or if command

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am web scraping the information of this web page **https://www.bundesbank.de/en/bundesbank/research/research-centre/people/people-738992.**
The web page has different sections such as Head of Research, this section has 12 researchers, and when you click on one option, you go to the web page of each researcher.
So far this is my code, and I can web scrape the contents of each researcher, but is there a way to have a single code (and not 12) to web scrape the information of all the researchers of Head of Research section? I am not sure if it is better to web scrape this with a "loop", "while loop", or an "if"  command

```
from selenium import webdriver
mozilla_path = r"C:\Users\ivrav\Python38\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bundesbank.de/en/bundesbank/research/research-centre/people/people-738992")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="top"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li/div/a""").click()
Researcher =driver.find_element_by_class_name("main")
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the info on those in the Research Centre, try changing your last two lines to:

```
researchers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[.="Research Assistants"]//preceding-sibling::div[@class="collection mb-4"]//a[@class="collection__link"]')
for researcher in researchers:
        print(researcher.text, researcher.get_attribute('href'))
```

Output:

```
Kartik Anand https://www.bundesbank.de/en/kartik-anand
Sven Blank https://www.bundesbank.de/en/sven-blank
Ana-Maria Dumitru https://www.bundesbank.de/en/ana-maria-dumitru
```

etc.

You can now follow each researcher's link to the appropriate page and scrape that as per usual.